# EHOSTUNREACH- Error when trying to make requests to backend API via localhost

Tags: node.js, express, axios, macos-big-sur, ehostunreach

I have a small website I've been working on as part of a college assignment. Last time I worked on the project everything worked perfectly. However, since then I've upgraded to MacOS Big Sur which has caused me tonnes of issues and a new VPN client.
Now the frontend cannot make requests to the backend via localhost and I get this error:

```
Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 0.0.31.144:80 - Local (ip here)
    at internalConnect (net.js:923:16)
    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:351:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.emitLookup [as callback] (net.js:1063:9)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:68:8)
```

The frontend works fine on its own and the backend is also fine with postman.
This is the case with another project of mine too. At first I thought it was an issue with axios and big sur but I have a 3rd project that is running completely fine with axios. The only common thing I can see between the 2 broken projects is expressJS but can't seem to find a solution.
I'm at a complete loss with it